# Prove that the sum of the reciprocals of the curvature at opposite points in a planar curve of constant width $μ$ is equal to $μ.$

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis

Prove that the sum of the reciprocals of the curvature at opposite points in a planar curve of constant width $μ$  is equal to $μ.$

My attempt:-
I can write $\beta(s)=\alpha(s)+\mu N(s).$ I know that For any regular parametrized curve $α$, we have $κ=\frac{\| \alpha' \times \alpha''\|}{\|\alpha'\|}.$

I found $\beta(s)=\alpha(s)+\mu N(s)\implies \beta'(s)=\alpha'(s)+\mu N'(s)=\alpha'(s)+\mu(-\kappa(s)T(s)+\tau(s)B(s))\implies \beta''(s)=\alpha''(s)+\mu(-\kappa'(s)T(s)-\kappa(s)T'(s)+\tau'(s)B(s)+\tau(s)B'(s))=\alpha''(s)+\mu(-\kappa'(s)T(s)-\kappa^2(s)N(s)+\tau'(s)B(s)-\tau^2(s)N(s)) $

I am not able to simplify. Could you help me?

Comment: You need to compute the curvature of the NON-arclength-parametrized curve $\beta$. Use the fact that the unit tangent vector of $\beta$ at $s$ is the negative of the unit tangent vector $T(s)$ of $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A Geometric Approach**

Since the width of the curve $\gamma$ at any point is $\mu$, for any $t$, there is a $\rho(t)$ so that $|\gamma(\rho(t))-\gamma(t)|=\mu$. Since the curvature of $\gamma$ is assumed to exist at both $t$ and $\rho(t)$, $\gamma'$ exists at both $t$ and $\rho(t)$. Since $\mu$ is the diameter,
$$
\begin{align}
0
&=\mu\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}|\gamma(s)-\gamma(t)|_{s=\rho(t)}\tag{1a}\\
&=(\gamma(\rho(t))-\gamma(t))\cdot\gamma'(\rho(t))\tag{1b}
\end{align}
$$
That is,
$$
\gamma(\rho(t))-\gamma(t)\perp\gamma'(\rho(t))\tag2
$$
Similarly,
$$
\begin{align}
0
&=\mu\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}|\gamma(\rho(t))-\gamma(s)|_{s=t}\tag{3a}\\
&=(\gamma(t)-\gamma(\rho(t)))\cdot\gamma'(t)\tag{3b}
\end{align}
$$
Which says,
$$
\gamma(\rho(t))-\gamma(t)\perp\gamma'(t)\tag4
$$
Thus,
$$
\gamma'(t)\parallel\gamma'(\rho(t))\tag5
$$
Since the tangents at $\gamma(t)$ and $\gamma(\rho(t))$ are parallel, looking at $\gamma$ near $\gamma(t)$ and $\gamma(\rho(t))$, it looks like

[image]

where $\kappa$ is the curvature of $\gamma$.

Since the diameter is $\mu$, we have
$$
\frac1{\kappa(\gamma(t))}+\frac1{\kappa(\gamma(\rho(t)))}=\mu\tag6
$$

---

**Using the Formula in the Question**

Using that $\gamma$ and $\gamma+\mu N$ are the opposing points on $\gamma$, and that the formula for curvature is
$$
\kappa=\frac{\gamma'\times\gamma''}{|\gamma'|^3}\tag7
$$
Where the cross product in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the dot product of the first vector and the second vector rotated $\frac\pi2$ clockwise. This means that when a curve is turning left, $\kappa\gt0$. Furthermore, for the unit left-pointing normal, $N$,
$$
N'=-\kappa\gamma'\tag8
$$
which implies $(\gamma+\mu N)'=\gamma'(1-\mu\kappa)$ and $(\gamma+\mu N)''=\gamma''(1-\mu\kappa)-\gamma'\mu\kappa'$.

Thus, when we plug $\gamma+\mu N$ into $(7)$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{(\gamma+\mu N)'\times(\gamma+\mu N)''}{|(\gamma+\mu N)'|^3}
&=\frac{\gamma'\times\gamma''|1-\mu\kappa|^2}{|\gamma'|^3|1-\mu\kappa|^3}\tag{9a}\\
&=\frac{\kappa}{|1-\mu\kappa|}\tag{9b}
\end{align}
$$
If $\kappa\ge\frac1\mu$, then
$$
\frac1\kappa+\overbrace{\ \frac{\mu\kappa-1}{\kappa}\ }^{\substack{\text{reciprocal of}\\\text{the curvature at}\\\text{the opposite}\\\text{point}}}=\mu\tag{10}
$$
We cannot have $\mu\lt\frac1\kappa$ since then $\gamma+\mu N$ is not a point of maximal distance from $\gamma$:

[image]

Note that $\gamma+\mu N$ is actually a point of minimal distance from $\gamma$.

Comment: Why $\kappa \ge \frac{1}{\mu}$?

Comment: What does this statement "Where the cross product in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the dot product of the first vector and the second vector rotated $\frac\pi2$ clockwise. This means that when a curve is turning left, $\kappa\gt0$. Furthermore, for the unit left-pointing normal, $N$,
$$
N'=-\kappa\gamma'\tag8
$$" mean?

Comment: The ststement is attempting to describe a cross product on $\mathbb{R}^2$ since it is normally defined on $\mathbb{R}^3$. $a\times b=a\cdot\rho(b)$, where $\rho$ rotates a vector $\frac\pi2$ clockwise. $(8)$ relates the derivative of $N$ to the derivative of $\gamma$.

Comment: If $\mu\lt\frac1\kappa$, then $\gamma+\mu N$ is not a point of maximal distance from $\gamma$.

Comment: If $μ<1/κ$
, then  why $γ+μN$
 is not a point of maximal distance from $γ$?
.

Comment: I have added some explanation at the end.